# Why doesn't user deletion work in Django, working on AWS EC2?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, nginx, amazon-ec2

So I've deployed my Django project with AWS EC2. I'm using Ubuntu OS and Nginx. Also, I'm using Django's built-in authentication system for registration.
 I have a test user whom I'd like to delete now. So in 'Authentication' -> "User" in Django admin, I selected the user and tried deleting it. But then it returned an error, saying `TypeError at /admin/auth/user/ : __str__ returned non-string (type tuple)` 
Since I'm using the built-in authentication, I have not created any model regarding it. What do you think can be the problem? Thank you very much in advance :)

Comment: It is hard to say anything without seeing any of your models; but my guess is you have a model with a `ForeignKey` to the `User` model; and the `__str__` method in that model returns a tuple instead of a string. Django Admin tries to print a list of all affected related model instances before deleting a record and fails.

Comment: @Selcuk Oh so then would I have to check all models that have Users as foreign key?

Comment: Yes. Do you have a traceback? If yes, edit your question to include that.

Comment: @Selcuk Ah, thank you so much. I fixed a model that has users as foreign key, and it solved the problem. Appreciate it very much :)